# How to hide Family sharing option from AppStore?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have released new app in Appstore and all looking good. But When I looking on my app at bottom of the page, I can see **Family Sharing option under Supports section**. I don't want show this family sharing option for my app in appstore.

So can anyone tell me how to hide this Family Sharing option ?

Please see the screen shot here

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: We're in the same boat. I've gone through all of our IAP Products and confirmed that none of them have Family Sharing enabled. So it's s total mystery right now why our app's page in the App Store is showing the same indication.